Weighted Average and System of Equations
Suppose I have all discrete distributions over the reals with support size N. So, I have a set of all possible weights $A=\{\alpha\in [0,1]^N:\sum_i^N\alpha_i=1\}$. Fix $\hat{b}$. Now suppose I have that for each $\alpha\in A,$ there exists a set $b^{\alpha}$ such that:
$\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i b^{\alpha}_i = \hat{b}$.
I know that the weighted averages are all equal to $\hat{b}$ and I can see the $\alpha$, but I cannot see/do not know the $b^{\alpha}$. I want to know if this system of equations implies that $b^{alpha}_i = \hat{b}$ for all $\alpha$ and for all $i$. I think I know it doesn't, but I want additional restrictions to ensure this. I cannot freely change my $\alpha$.
I want to know how I can ensure that all $b's$ are equal to $\hat{b}$. Thanks!
I can, for example, add numbers that I can see to each b.
